# DIV overlay with css

Tags: html, css

There may be a simple solution, but I can't seem to figure this out. I'm taking a design I made and turning it into a live site. There is a gradient background and a dark overlay layer for effect. I can't seem to place the content above the overlay.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmtj6.jpg

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="container main">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
        /* Gradient: */
background: #08a8d4;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #08a8d4 7%, #04ffc4 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(7%,#08a8d4), color-stop(100%,#04ffc4));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #08a8d4 7%,#04ffc4 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #08a8d4 7%,#04ffc4 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #08a8d4 7%,#04ffc4 100%);
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #08a8d4 7%,#04ffc4 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#08a8d4', endColorstr='#04ffc4',GradientType=1 );


}

.overlay {
height: 100%;
opacity: 0.26;
background: #535353;
position: relative;

}

.main {
    margin-top: 50px;

}

.main h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Also please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: try setting some `z-index`

Comment: It's not clear from your image what the overlay is. Please post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with full html. Also, if you need IE8 support it's not wise to set opacity and an opaque background color because opacity will be ignored. Instead, apply an rgba bg-color.

Answer (score 1):

change the

```
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.26;
  background: #535353;
  position: relative;
}
```

to

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.26;
  background: #535353;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CSS z-index option.
apply a z-index:100 to the content you want raised

Answer (score 0):

you should place your `.container.main` outside of `.overlay` and then use `position: absolute` on either

```
<div class="overlay">
</div>

<div class="container main">
    {{> yield}}
</div>
```

assign `position: absolute` on either `.overlay` or `.container` and make sure the container of both these two elements has also `position` property defined